# iTunesConnect Bug? Product of In-App-Purchase Can't "Submit For Review"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I've tried hundreds time of this direction but still can not make my In App Purchase available for "Submit For Review":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html

**This happened after once of IAP rejection. That was correct with whole new app.**

I am sure my app status was "Prepare For Submission", and had clicked "+" to add my IAP product here on the App Details Section: "In App Purchase".

But, it always complains I didn't add the product into the new version like this, I can't "Submit For Review" forever:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10368945_10203071355008251_1649616864978115808_o.jpg

Comment: what is the reason of rejection of ur app in resolution center ?

Comment: Rejection reason 2.2 like this, they said they can't purchase when review, and rejected it ask me to delete the old IAP product:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10628246_10203047317007316_6760281094115915342_n.jpg?oh=7e690938279ade70fa20fb79dcde730c&oe=54E6044C&__gda__=1427668275_643cd8463127951f2670739ceca349d7

Comment: your inapppurchase implementation is wrong man,try with test user

Comment: 2.2 was past, forget it, I deleted it forever. My question is NEW FIRST IAP ADDED "AFTER" DELETED THE REJECTED ONE, THEN THE NEW ONE(S) CAN NOT BE SUBMITTED.

Comment: if you deleted ur app, then u can't upload ur project with same identifier,appname

Comment: it's "IAP" deleted, not "app" deleted.

Comment: ok,currently what problem you r facing ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have confirmed the answer below with Apple support guy.

**If their is NO IAP of an app before, then when I want to add a new one, the process will be a little different with those app which has one or some IAP products already.**

Let me simulate the steps of an app which I want to add the first IAP product:

> 1. **Step 1**: create an new IAP product with unique ID, reference name.
> 2. **Step 2**: Fill up all content of the new IAP product, include at least one language item, save the product.
> 3. **Step 3**: Test the IAP product on the iOS device and get a screenshot, then upload the image in the section of "Screenshot for
>      Review".
> 4. **Step 4**: Save the product again, and make sure the status of product is "Ready to Submit", but DON'T CARE THE RIGHT TOP BUTTON
>      "Submit For Review" IS GRAY, DISABLE, just click "Done" at the Down
>      Right.
> 5. **Step 5**: Go to App Version information page, make sure the app status is "Prepare for Submission", "Developer Rejected", "Metadata
>      Rejected", or some other "Rejected".
> 6. **Step 6**. In the section "In App Purchase (+)" of the Version info. page, click the "(+)", and select the new IAP product to be checked,
>      click "Done".
> 7. **Step 7**. Upload a binary, add the binary to the "Build (+)", CLICK "Submit For Review" OF THE VERSION INFO. PAGE, THEN DONE.
> 8. **Step 8**. Go to the "In App Purchase" page, make sure the FIRST NEW IAP product's status being "Waiting For Review", and a "PENDING" icon
>      on it.

If there is some old IAP product with approved previous version of app, within only this condition, the developer can select newer IAP products in the "In App Purchase" Page, and can click the BRIGHT YELLOW "Submit For Review" BUTTON on the page top.

Comment:  I forgot Step 6 and my app was accepted without the IAP!
Thanks for taking the time to describe your steps.

Comment: Ahaa. Yup, step 6 was also the culprit. Thank you!!