# In App purchased product not found but already setup on itune connect year 2017

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Hello guys I am having issue on in-app purchased' here what I have done.

First I add my product id in ituneconnect example product id "com.myweb.myappname.product1" and my bundle Identifier in my ios project is "com.myweb.myappname".

The status of my product ID is Ready to Submit but my problem is I cannot submit it because' the Save and Submit for Review button is disabled.

How to resolved this?

I used this code to tes in app purchased code but the result is always "NO product Found..".

```
//my bundle Identifier = com.myweb.myappname

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"product_ids"
                                                 withExtension:@"plist"];
NSArray *productIdentifiers = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *myfirstrpodcuct = [productIdentifiers objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"myfirstrpodcuct = %@",myfirstrpodcuct); //this display my product id com.myweb.myappname.product1

if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:myfirstrpodcuct, nil]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Cannot used inApp Purchased.");
}                

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
     didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    self.products = response.products;
    if(response.products.count != 0){
        NSLog(@"Product Found..");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO product Found..");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        // Handle any invalid product identifiers.
        NSLog(@"Handle any invalid product identifiers");
    }
    NSLog(@"displayStoreUI");
   // [self displayStoreUI]; // Custom method
}
```

I also tried to archived the project and submit the binary to ituneconnect.  Then I used testflight to test the app but still the product not found.. any idea?

Comment: Contract, tax and banking should be filled and approved to use any in-app purchase operations, including testing. So check whether that information is filled or not

Comment: hello Sivajee Battina how to check if it is already approved or not? sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: Did you fill the information related to banking? in itunes connect. Please verify

Comment: If you filled the information already, check this link for next steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901542/itunesconnect-bug-product-of-in-app-purchase-cant-submit-for-review

Comment: Hello my office mate just setup Contract, tax and banking then the in-app purchase status become "Waiting for Upload" what doest it mean? should I upload new binary using application loader?